# Flutter project : no Android highlighting

Tags: android-studio

I have my flutter project running and compiling. Dart mistakes are highlighted and android studio make some proposition to fix it.

But There is nothing similar deeper in my android folder (ex: `./android/app/src/main/java/com/path/MainActivity.java`). I have to compile to see errors and correct them one after the other.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is caused by missing .iml project files.
These files are added automatically to the **.gitignore** file,

to avoid that in the future just edit **.gitignore** and remove .iml

<s>this is already an [open issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54092) in the flutter repository.</s>

to add those files again to your project just write :

> `flutter create .`

the missing files will be added.

Answer (score 2):

To develop the Android and iOS parts of your application you can simply open the corresponding modules.

Either:

- from the window toolbar: Tools -> Flutter -> Open for Editing in Android Studio
  [image: Toolbar Open for Editing in Android]
- or right click the 'android' folder, Flutter -> Open Android Module in Android Studio.
  [image: Context Menu]

Comment: Sorry, I can't do that: Fist option, I do not have "Open ..." in the list; Second option, Flutter choice is grey, I can't click on it.

Comment: @Jérémy are you sure you waited for indexing to finish? while android studio is indexing, these options are not available

Comment: Totally sure ! Nothing is running background, my android studio is open for days.

Comment: @Jérémy have you tried running 'flutter doctor' on the command line, if everything is set up correctly? you can also try in android studio File -> Invalidate Caches & Restart -> "Invalidate and Restart" .. and make sure on startup you see a 'Indexing' progress in the status bar..

Comment: Flutter doctor tell me that 'flutter plugin' and 'dart plugin' are not installed. But they are according to Andoid studio > file > settings > plugin. I also invalidate the cache and restarted android studio. "indexing" apeared. I had to sync the project. But nothing changed : can't have the same menu than on your screenshots.

Comment: @Jérémy maybe you opened the project as android project in the first place, instead of as flutter project? in the "Project" Tool window is your project shown with a Flutter Icon? maybe you could share a screenshot of your setup

Comment: The icon is flutter's logo, exept in the small left tall bar: https://prnt.sc/n8ei3l

Comment: @jeremy This is seriously weird.. have you tried opening the android folder directly in Android studio? First run your android app to make sure all project files are there.. and then file -> open -> existing android project.. and select the android folder directly inside your project

Comment: I've already done this, but there is to many lines highlighted in red, because Android doesn't recognize some imports from Flutter.